# Geometry Transformations proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider three lines $L_1,L_2,L_3$, with
$L_1 \perp L_2$ at point $A$ and $L_1 \perp L_3$ at point $B$.
$H_A,H_B$ denote point reflections (half turns) at the points $A, B$ respectively.
$R_1$ is a reflection at the line $L_1$ etc.

Prove $H_A R_3 = R_2 H_B$

I found $H_A = R_2 R_1$ and $H_B = R_3 R_1$ so
$H_A R_3 = R_2 H_B$ which is 
$(R_2R_1)R_3 = R_2(R_3R_1)$ by subsitution.
Now multiply by $R_2$ so we get:
$R_2R_2R_1R_3 = R_2R_2R_3R_1$ and simplify:
$I R_1R_3 = I R_3R_1$

I am unsure of where to go now.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail on what L, H, R, A and B are?

Comment: $L$ is just arbitrary lines. $H$ are half turns $R$ are reflections. $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary points

Comment: So $R_2$ is a reflection over $L_2$

Comment: Well, you were on the right track, but you also have $H_B = R_1 R_3$. Use that instead of $H_B = R_3 R_1$, which is also correct, but not as useful here. By the way, in general if you have two reflections $R$ and $R'$, then usually $RR' \ne R'R$. But this is not the case if $R$ and $R'$ are with respect to perpendicular lines.